# Getting 401 status code HP alm rest api for "/defects/defectid" api

Tags: java, api, rest, alm

I am trying to access HP alm rest api.

1. i am able to get 200 OK response for /authentication-point/authenticate api
2. I am able to get 201 for POST /rest/site-session api. Session is being created.
3. but when i am trying to hit /rest/domain/{domain-name}/projects/{project-name}/defect; i am getting 401 status code with below error.

Reason - authentication failed

I tried to pass all headers from /authenticate and /site-session to this api. But still getting 401 error code.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same issue as Mahadev and i was able to resolve it.

The issue was the way in which the cookies was passed along the request.

Instead of this :

```
    invocationBuilder.cookie("LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY", lswoocookie);
    invocationBuilder.cookie("QCSession", qcsessioncookie);
    res = invocationBuilder.get();
```

Pass the cookies in the header as a concatenated String as shown below:

```
String concatenatedHeaderCookieString = "QCSession=" + qcsessioncookie + ";" + "ALM_USER=" + ";" + almuser + ";" + "XSRF-TOKEN=" + xsrftoken + ";"+ "LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=" + lswoocookie;

     invocationBuilder.header("Cookie", concatenatedHeaderCookieString);
     res = invocationBuilder.get();
```

Result : InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=https://xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.com/qcbin/rest/domains/RELEASES/projects/2019/defects/1, status=200, reason=OK}}

And this would work like a charm!